# posting images in a form

Tags: image, netsuite, imagesource

I am using free marker in a netsuite environment. I have a custom items field that displays an image and I need this image to appear on a quote document we send to our customers when they ask about a machine. All of our machines are one-offs so I need the system to pull in that information each time, rather than post one image and use html to insert into the template. I have been able to do this with custom text fields but have not been able to make it work with an image... I am still searching the help files but any assistance will be appreciated. Just point me in the right direct...;-)

Comment: Include some example code and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thanks... I found the code on NetSuite's help and it is close to working. The forms now show a graphic where the image should be.

The initial #if clause is wrong but the image src is correct; I am working through nowl. 

  <#if subsidiary.logo?length != 0>
        <img src="${record.custitemfec_custfield_image?length}" style="float: left; margin: 7px"/>
         <#else>
                <#if companyInformation.logoUrl?length != 0>
                        <img src="${record.custitemfec_custfield_image?length}" style="float: left; margin: 7px" />
                </#if>
</#if>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
${record.custitemfec_custfield_image?length}
```

probably needs to be:

```
${record.custitemfec_custfield_image}
```

Also it looks like you are trying to print a record for an item. Is that correct? If you are trying to print a transaction you probably want:

```
<img src="${record.item[0].item.custitemfec_custfield_image}" style="float: left; margin: 7px" />
```

or

```
<#list record.item as line>
...
    <img src="${line.item.custitemfec_custfield_image}" style="float: left; margin: 7px" /> 
...
</#list
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the guidance. Let me try these edits and see if they work. The challenge is all of this forms are for printing... Our site is heavily customized and we are wondering if this is even possible.... I will circle back with results after I try these but thank you....